# UITableView Selection - Checking cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I intend to have a UITableView filled with entries from an NSMutableDictionary. What I would like to do is when checking a cell, it creates an array which contains the key's objects.

The table view's cell.textLabel.text is equal to the key of each element of the dictionary, while the object associated with the key is an integer.

Let's say I tap one of the cells, and the object associated with it is 5722. I want to add that to the array, and check the cell as well. Also, tapping the cell again should remove the object associated with it and uncheck the cell. How do I go about doing this?

As of now, when scrolling, my checkmarks go everywhere.

Comment: check your cellforrowatindexpath. test it without using a reusable cell. if that helps, then figure out how to do it while reusing a cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are better of having your datasource as an NSArray instance. The list of keys provided by the allKeys method of the NSDictionary instance is not ordered and will change at any time. If you use an array, you can store the selected cells using an NSMutableIndexSet, and use this instance to get the records that have been selected from the array using the NSArray method objectsAtIndexes

Comment: The reason I am using a dictionary is because I need to have the key (a course title) associated with its object (a course ID), so that when the user selects the courses, the ID's are added to an array because they are what's important.

Comment: you can have an array, and use the objects of the array into the keys of the dictionary.